# React Native: Compressing Video when sending it to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, video-processing, aws-amplify

I'd like to upload a video file to S3 using AWS-Amplify; however, I am a bit concerned about the size of these video files and would like to compress them if possible. I've tried using the react-native-video-compression library but the library seems to be a bit out of date as it does not link property in iOS and that seems to be a common problem among all the people trying to use it.

Is there another library that will compress the video file before sending it? Or is there some kind of video processing code that could be written within the application itself?

I have also tried looking into some kind of built in compression system for AWS S3 but I was not able to find anything. Is this something that might need to be done within a lambda trigger when a video file is being uploaded to S3?

Comment: Most digital video is already compressed.